# How can I trigger a css animation multiple times using javascript and react in an optimal way?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance

I created a react component that is made of a 3d cube (using css) and 2 buttons that rotate this cube 90 degrees (1 button rotates the cube left and the other one right)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const rotateLeft = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const boxArea = document.getElementsByClassName("box-area")[0];
    const newNode = boxArea.cloneNode(true);
    boxArea.classList.add('rotateLeft');
    setTimeout(function(){
      boxArea.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, boxArea);
    }, 3005)
  };
  const rotateRight = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const boxArea = document.getElementsByClassName("box-area")[0];
    const newNode = boxArea.cloneNode(true);
    boxArea.classList.add('rotateRight');
    setTimeout(function(){
      boxArea.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, boxArea);
    }, 3005)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="hexagon-panel">
          <div className="wrapper">
              <div className="box-area">
                <div className="box front"/>
                <div className="box back"/>
                <div className="box left"/>
                <div className="box right"/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="hexagon-actions">
            <button onClick={rotateLeft}>Left</button>
            <button onClick={rotateRight}>Right</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, I trigger the animation by adding the class, I wait a bit more than 3 seconds (the animation lasts 3 seconds) and then I replace the Node with one that doesn't contain the class.

A better solution (but I don't like it either) is to remove the class after the animation ends.

```
  const rotateLeft = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const boxArea = document.getElementsByClassName("box-area")[0];
       boxArea.classList.add('rotateLeft');
       setTimeout(function(){
       boxArea.classList.remove('rotateLeft');
    }, 4000)
  };
```

But I am not convinced. The reason for this is the `setTimeout` since it is a global function I am afraid of a memory leak (even if it is a small one). Calling a new `setTimeout` on every click and not erasing the previous one.

I was thinking about this

```
  const rotateLeft = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const boxArea = document.getElementsByClassName("box-area")[0];
       boxArea.classList.add('rotateLeft');
       const func = setTimeout(function(){
         boxArea.classList.remove('rotateLeft');
       }, 4000)
       clearTimeout(func);
  };
```

But I don't know if that even makes sense.

Is there a way a better way to remove the class without the use of `setTimeout`? Or in the case that it is needed, what would be a good practice to delete it?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this: [Using Animation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#using_animation_events). It includes the `animationend` event that fires when the animation ends.

Or in the future, you could use the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) once it is widely implemented.

Or if you want to stick with `setTimeout`, just put the cleanup code (`clearTimeout`, remove class, etc.) before starting the animation. This way, you always get a 'clean' state to work with.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the animation events. About the 'clearTimeout' solution, can you put a snippet as an example? I am not following too well